# Selecting Checkboxes, Radio buttons and list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem checking/selecting radiobuttons, checkboxes and list styles at runtime using jQuery/jQuery Mobile.

Basically I have a list of checkboxes, radio buttons and select menus and what I would like to do is get the value from the database and select/tick the correct item from the checkbox/radio button group or select menu.

Here is a simple setup of what I have tried, but it did not work.

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">     
  <input type="radio" name="option_radio" id="option_radio_1" value="1" />
  <label for="option_radio_1">Option 1</label>  
  <input type="radio" name="option_radio" id="option_radio_2" value="2" />
  <label for="option_radio_2">Option 2</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">     
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_checkbox" id="option_checkbox_1" value="1" />
  <label for="option_checkbox_1">Option 1</label>   
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_checkbox2" id="option_checkbox_2" value="2" />
  <label for="option_checkbox_2">Option 2</label>   
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_checkbox3" id="option_checkbox_3" value="3" />
  <label for="option_checkbox_3">Option 3</label>
</fieldset>

<select name="option_list" id="option_list">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#option_checkbox_1").val(option_id); 
$("#option_list").val(optionlist_id);
$('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val(gender_id);
```

What I tried is passing the value from the database (example 1/2/3/4 etc) from the database directly to the element.

Can anyone tell me how this should be done exactly?

Comment: So what is the problem getting value from database or selecting the correct item?

Comment: @AleksandrM Sorry for not making my point clear.  Getting values from the database is ok.  The issue is selecting the radio buttons/checkboxes/list item that matches the value stored in the database

Comment: what are the values hold by option_id or optionlist_id variables? is it 0 to make unchecked or 1 to make it checked? please make it clearer. we need to know what values are returned for each variable so we can know how will it select or how it will check something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check it or give a value:

```
$('#option_checkbox_1').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('input:radio[id=option_radio_1]').attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#option_list").val(50);
```

and for un-checking (by removing the attribute entirely) do

```
$('#option_checkbox_1').removeAttr('checked');
$('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

I think here is what you want

```
$('#option_checkbox_'+option_id).attr('checked', 'checked');
$('input:radio[id='+gender_id+']').attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#option_list").val(optionlist_id);
```

Comment: `$('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').attr('checked', 'checked');` Check what is checked :)

Comment: @rkp if for example for the radio button group, the option to select (as stored in the database) is option 2.  How can I check the correct radio button?  (same issue for the others)

Comment: Strictly speaking `checked` is a property (rather than an attribute), so to make an element `checked`: `$(selector).prop('checked',true);`, to remove the check: `$(selector).prop('checked', false)` (*not* `removeProp()`).

Comment: @AleksandrM  I do not want to check what is checked as such.  I need to check them dynamically based on the values returned from the database.  I am thinking of having to check the value returned from the database and then using if/else use the solution mentioned by rkp to set the checked attribute.  Not sure if there's an easier way out

Comment: @user1809790 that's the thing im asking earlier. the check status, the  selection of select boxes depends on the values of the variables. we need to know what are these values

Answer (score 1):

`$("#option_checkbox_1").val(option_id);`

This is used to assign the value to the element .

You can `Element with attribute value selector` to find the element .

```
var valueFromDB = "1";
$("input[type='radio']['"+valueFromDB+"']").attr("checked","true");
$("input[type="checkbox"]['"+valueFromDB+"']").attr("checked","true");
$("#option_list option[value="20"]").attr("selected","true");
```

Another Point .

`id` is an unique for an element . You can't use `id` for multiple elements .

Answer (score 1):

To select the `input` element that has a particular value:

```
$('input[value=' + valueFromDatabase + ']');
```

To then check/select that element:

```
$('input[value=' + valueFromDatabase + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

This can, of course, be combined with other selectors (such as the `:radio`, or `:checkbox`):

```
$('input:radio[value=' + valueFromDatabase + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

If the value from the database contains *any* white-space, though, the value *must* be quoted in the selector, giving:

```
$('input[value="' + valueFromDatabase + '"]');
```

(Note the `"` characters surrounding the `valueFromDatabase.)

Answer (score 0):

That JS will set the value of the elements, it won't check them. What you want to do is use an if statement to see if the value of the radio/checkbox/select matches that of the string you're pulling from the database. If it does you then want to set the attribute to be checked/selected like so

```
// checkboxes/radios
$(this).attr('checked','checked')

// options
$(this).attr('selected','selected')
```

where $(this) = the input or the option

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself: `checked` is a property (rather than an attribute), so to make an element checked: `$(selector).prop('checked',true);`, to remove the check: `$(selector).prop('checked', false)` (*not* `removeProp()`).

Comment: @DavidThomas it does cause some confusion but both checked and selected are commonly referred to as attributes by w3c (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)